# How to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}\sqrt{x+1}=0$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to prove:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}\sqrt{x+1}=0$$

I don't understand what to do with: $$x\rightarrow -1^+$$

Comment: $x\to -1^+$ means we are taking $x\to -1$ and $x>-1$.

Comment: It means "the limit as $x$ approaches $-1$ from above" i.e. only values greater than $-1$. This is because for values of $x$ less than $-1$, the function is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal two-sided limit, we'd want to prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$
0 < |x + 1| < \delta \implies |\sqrt{x + 1} - 0| < \epsilon
$$
But since we are approaching $-1$ from the right, we are assuming that $x > -1$, which implies that $x + 1 > 0$ (so that we aren't taking the square root of a negative number). This allows us to safely drop the absolute values, so we may simplify the above implication a bit to become:
$$
0 < x + 1 < \delta \implies |\sqrt{x + 1} - 0| < \epsilon
$$

---

Indeed, given any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \epsilon^2 > 0$. Then if $0 < x + 1 < \delta$, notice that:
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x + 1} - 0|
&= \sqrt{x + 1} \\
&< \sqrt{\epsilon^2} &\text{since }x + 1 < \delta = \epsilon^2\\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: OK, but it's not clear for me: $$< \sqrt{\epsilon^2}$$ Where did you get it?

Comment: Without knowing to let $\delta = \epsilon^2$, all we would have is:
$$
\sqrt{x + 1} < \sqrt{\delta}
$$
So the natural substitution to force $\sqrt{\delta} = \epsilon$ would be to set $\delta = \epsilon^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation used means that $x$ goes to $-1$ *from above* (else the function wouldn't be real-valued), alternative notation is
$$\lim_{x\searrow -1} \sqrt{1+x} = \lim_{x\to-1, x>-1} \sqrt{1+x} = \lim_{x\to-1^+} \sqrt{1+x}$$
So you have to show that $\forall\epsilon > 0\ \exists\delta > 0$ such that
$$\sqrt{1+(-1+h)} <\epsilon \quad\forall 0< h<\delta$$
Where normal $\epsilon-\delta$ (for the two-sided limit) would require $\forall h: |h|<\delta$.

Comment: What does $h$ mean?

Comment: @qexi $h$ is any real number in $(0,\delta)$, as it says. You may have seen
$$|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon \quad\forall y: |x-y|<\delta$$
As the definition. Then simply pick $y = x+h$ with $x$ fixed to obtain my definition.

Comment: So, if I have for example: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}3x+1=4$ $$0<|x-1|<\delta$$ In this case $h=|x-1|$, right?

Comment: @qexi Almost. $h = x-1$ (signed). The $h>0$ comes from the one-sided limit statement ($x\searrow-1$). Else you'd get $-\delta <h<\delta$.